# http: TLS handshake error from 10.203.3.195:58328: read tcp 10.203.88.141:9443->10.203.3.195:58328: read: connection reset by peer

Tags: amazon-elb

I have a question, which is not fully/100% Datadog one - we have an aws-load-balancer-controller (https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/aws/aws-load-balancer-controller/1.5.4) set up within our EKS cluster . A strange log, which only Datadog detected, related to the ELB is that one :

2023/06/30 07:25:00 http: TLS handshake error from 10.203.3.195:48624: read tcp 10.203.88.141:9443->10.203.3.195:48624: read: connection reset by peer
2023/06/30 07:40:00 http: TLS handshake error from 10.203.3.195:58196: read tcp 10.203.88.141:9443->10.203.3.195:58196: read: connection reset by peer
2023/06/30 07:45:00 http: TLS handshake error from 10.203.3.195:47312: read tcp 10.203.88.141:9443->10.203.3.195:47312: read: connection reset by peer
2023/06/30 08:05:00 http: TLS handshake error from 10.203.3.195:59076: read tcp 10.203.88.141:9443->10.203.3.195:59076: read: connection reset by peer
2023/06/30 08:10:00 http: TLS handshake error from 10.203.3.195:39446: read tcp 10.203.88.141:9443->10.203.3.195:39446: read: connection reset by peer
2023/06/30 08:15:00 http: TLS handshake error from 10.203.3.195:35556: read tcp 10.203.88.141:9443->10.203.3.195:35556: read: connection reset by peer
2023/06/30 08:25:00 http: TLS handshake error from 10.203.3.195:52352: read tcp 10.203.88.141:9443->10.203.3.195:52352: read: connection reset by peer
2023/06/30 08:25:00 http: TLS handshake error from 10.203.3.195:52356: read tcp 10.203.88.141:9443->10.203.3.195:52356: read: connection reset by peer
2023/06/30 08:25:00 http: TLS handshake error from 10.203.3.195:52366: read tcp 10.203.88.141:9443->10.203.3.195:52366: read: connection reset by peer
2023/06/30 08:30:00 http: TLS handshake error from 10.203.3.195:45512: read tcp 10.203.88.141:9443->10.203.3.195:45512: read: connection reset by peer
By making a research this repeatable IP corresponds to the default Kubernetes endpoint, as you can see.

k get endpoints
NAME         ENDPOINTS                          AGE
kubernetes   10.203.2.46:443,10.203.3.195:443   688d

Can you please help me, regarding that strange issue?

Bumping the Helm Chart's version to the latest one and changing the TLS/SSL ELB's security policy from 'ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08' to the recommended from AWS one - 'ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS13-1-2-2021-06' with the defaultSSLPolicy helm chart's parameter.

I expect to not having such log messages, despite they are not impacting the performance of the app at all.